# jquery mouseleave also firing during enter

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I have a simple jquery code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=0;
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){

            $('body').append(++i+'<br/>');
        });
    });
```

This code is firing even when the mouse enters the browser window. How do I make it fire only when the mouse leaves the browser window ? This is a problem in **chrome** for me.

Working example here : **http://tapasdwivedi.com/test1/**

Comment: Firefox - fires only on leaving window, not firing on entering

Comment: Thanks. It just worked for me in firefox too. But not working in chrome. Have edited the question.

Comment: It's working in chrome too: http://jsfiddle.net/ektuzng4/

Comment: Yes. I tested in a fiddle myself where it was working. But if you check my page, and the source code - Its not working.

Comment: @C-linkNepal for me it's working in JSFiddle, not working in page. @soundswaste - try changing `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()`

Comment: Yeah, it's amazed me...

Comment: I have tried this code from chrome on two completely different sites (one on godaddy, other on aws) .. been working on this for 5 hours now!

Comment: Btw, even in your fiddle - if you move the mouse towards the bottom on the windows toolbar, you will see the same issue that i am facing. It starts firing for both enter and leave.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=0;
  $(this).mouseenter(function(){
    return false;
  });
  $(this).mouseleave(function(){
    $('body').append(++i+'<br/>');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bit of an issue with the latest release of Chrome. It's being discussed here : https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce/issues/48 and here : https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce/pull/55 by guys who are trying to develop a plugin for this functionality I am trying to implement.

The only workaround I see right now is adding a setTimeout of 3000ms, assuming most visitors will have entered the window by 3 seconds :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).mouseleave(function(e){
       if(i==0){
           $('body').append('hello<br/>');
           ++i;
       }
    });
},3000);
```

This isnt much of an answer, but I am keeping it here till someone gives a solid one.